# Can anyone help me convert a table such as this example into a dynamic one in Javascript by using the for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Can anyone help me learn how to convert an HTML table into a dynamic Javascript table using the for loop? This is an example I found in my book and wanted to see how I could go about doing this.

---

Heading There is sections of the table that need to have the rows combined and he columns combined. I have been struggling with this for some time. Any help would be appreciated. I did not include the CSS portion of the code only the table.

---

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan= "3" class= "MH">Conversion Tables</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3" class="heading1">Meters to 
        <br />Feet</th>
        <td>1 meter</td>
        <td>3.28 feet</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="difrow">
        <td>50 meters</td>
        <td>164.04 feet</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>100 meters</td>
        <td>328.08 feet</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="difrow">
        <th rowspan="3" class="heading1">Kilometers to
        <br />Miles</th>
        <td>1 kilometer</td>
        <td>0.62 miles</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>50 kilometers</td>
        <td>31.07 miles</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="difrow">
        <td>100 kilometers</td>
        <td>62.14 miles</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mittal Don't forget  to fix the tags when editing :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can add id attribute to table tag then call a javascript method on page load:

```html
<table class="table" id="tableId">
```

```js
function createRows(){
   
    var items = "<tr><td></td></tr>...";
    document.getElementById("tableId").innerHTML = items; 

}
```

in javascript method you can use for to generate table rows.